# How can I prevent double entries, and to only trigger only 1 buy alert at a time followed by a sell?

Tags: pine-script

In Tradingview, sometimes the buy alerts trigger twice, even though I'm using the 4hr chart (one per bar) and repainting should be minimal. Is there a way to enforce this in the code? Sometimes the code triggers 3 entries and then an exit. The conditions are shown below:

```
longEnter = ta.crossover(closeSeriesAlt, openSeriesAlt)
longExit = ta.crossunder(closeSeriesAlt, openSeriesAlt)

alertcondition(longEnter, title = "Enter Long", message = "Enter Long")
alertcondition(longExit, title = "Exit Long", message = "Exit Long")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `barstate.isconfirmed` to your condition. This way, your condition will be evaluated on the last tick of the bar and will not repaint.

> barstate.isconfirmed
>
> Returns true if the script is calculating the last (closing) update of
> the current bar. The next script calculation will be on the new bar
> data.

Comment: I tried adding barstate.isconfirmed, it didn't work, but my knowledge of coding is limited. Could you kindly show me an example based on my alert conditions. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

...

// Check if the current bar is confirmed
is_confirmed = barstate.isconfirmed

alertcondition(longEnter and is_confirmed, "Enter Long", "Enter Long")
alertcondition(longExit and is_confirmed, "Exit Long", "Exit Long")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).